# Trouble growing radish seeds

Tags: seeds, germination, radishes

Recently I've been trying out growing seeds in a seedling tray, I sowed them about a week and a half ago but they've seemed to make little progress.

They were kept in a little greenhouse tray and not in direct sunlight, with water moderately sprayed on them. Some seedlings have emerged, but just stopped in their progress for some reason in the pictures below. Not too sure why they won't emerge, any suggestions.

[image][image]

Comment: I wonder if the soil was moist enough.   FWIW, I grew some using "the baggie method" and then transplanted the germinated seeds and it worked a treat.    TO use the baggie method, throughly wet a tissue or paper towel, fold into quarters or more, lay out seeds in center of tissue, put in a clear ziplock bag and leave to germinate.   Once the plants have started growing roots transplant them.  Radishes should germinate in less then a week in temps of 15-30c

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect a problem with the soil. The fact that the ones that did germinate weren't growing well seems indicative of that.

Possible problems include these:

- Herbicide in the soil
- Too many wood chips in the soil (adding more nitrogen could potentially help in this case)
- Soil that is too salty (or that has a high salt index; salt doesn't just mean sodium chloride, but that is one chemical salt)
- Disease in the soil
- Mites or some such attacking the new seedlings after they sprout
- Improper kinds of light
- Improper light levels
- Temperatures that are too low or too high
- Improper moisture levels (too little or too much; drying out too much between waterings, etc.)
- Seeds with issues (like low germination rates, disease, etc.)
- Your water might have issues (like too much sodium in it)
- Improper soil amendments

Answer (score 1):

Radishes, to germinate require ample low temperatures. If you're living somewhere where you get the right conditions for radish germination then perhaps the seeds are a bit too old/ compromised.

Also, plant them straight into compost. Add a bit of perlite
and vermiculite or alluvial soil to the mixture. Lignin produced by cardboard in compost can potentially kill plants.

---